# xcode 6 swift cant add existing objects to different device storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I mistakenly added several items to the ipad storyboard of my app. It is causing a huge problem now that I want the same items on the iphone version of the storyboard. The buttons/labels appear in the view controller scene section of the document outline, but they are translucent and I cannot drag them to the storyboard. Does anyone know how to easily include these objects on the iphone storyboard as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, click in the transduced elements (similar to what is showing below:

[image]

Now check the option installed for each missing element in the property inspector.

[image]

I hope that helps!